# More button feature in html/.cshtml

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How we can put a more button in a .cshtml page? The expectation is to open a new non-editable text area when someone click on a more button.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it directly in the browser:

http://api.jquery.com/show/